# Different way of saying "Feuer!"

Tags: single-word-request

In certain war films, Germans are shown shouting "Feuer!" to give the order to open fire. However, during the movie U-571, the German U-boat commander (Thomas Kretschmann) shouted something that sounded like "lawss!" to fire a torpedo. Subtitles showed "Fire!" as he said that.

What's the exact word? I could find a similar word in German "los", which according to Google translate, it means "off". Could that be the word?

Comment: Before "fire" was used in terms of muskets there was "loose" to let arrows fly. It seems like a good word to use to open "open fire". You really don't want to confuse it with the panic word for open combustion on a submersible.
"Did you say you wanted us to shoot these things or that you've spotted a fire and you want us to come put it out?"

Comment: Indeed, [los](https://www.dwds.de/wb/los#et-1) and [loose](https://www.etymonline.com/word/loose#etymonline_v_12428) are cognates.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

"Los" is the German equivalent of English "Go" - as in "Ready, set, go" which is "Auf die Plätze, fertig, los" in German.

Thus it's a frequent choice when something is launched or set off.

Comment: Yep also to release / let something free. As when something is let loose, on the hunt et.c. "die Wachthunde loslassen".

Comment: In this context, this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 32):

"Fire" isn't really a very logical way to command the release of a torpedo - unlike Firearms and cannons, there isn't really a lot of fire involved underwater.

This is why the standard command to release a torpedo is, even today, in German "Torpedo los". In the movie, that was apparently shortened to "los".
"los" is a prefix for a lot of verbs that denotes release actions, like

- loslassen
- loslaufen
- ...

Comment: basically like "release"?

Comment: @RealCheeseLord basically "release", but it is better translated as "go!"

Comment: “los” is more than a prefix; it’s a [self-contained adverb or interjection](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/los_Aufforderung_locker) with a similar meaning as “weg” and cognate to the English “loose”. Another common nautical command is “Leinen los!” (“Cast off!”).

Comment: also as in ready-set-go, *Achtung, fertig, los!"

Answer (score 3):

Submarine warfare uses different wording for firing a torpedo.
The command "fire" is only used for declaring an emergency: something in the submarine is burning.

In order not to confuse the command to fire a torpedo with that emergency, a different command "Torpedo los!" is used.